# Is it possible change username in Amazon Cognito with iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, amazon-cognito

as written in the title is it possible change username of a Amazon Cognito user? I can't find anything in documentation

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible to update the `preferred_username` of a Cognito User using the iOS SDK, using the `updateAttributes` API call. However, kindly note that you would not be able to modify the `username` of a user. Quoting the official AWS documentation,

> The username value is a separate attribute and not the same as the
>   name attribute. A username is always required to register a user, and
>   it cannot be changed after a user is created.

But, the `preferred_username` value can indeed be changed, and a sample code to change the preferred username using the iOS SDK, as per the official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-ios-sdk.html) is stated as follows:

```
AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType * attribute = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType new];
attribute.name = @"preferred_username";
attribute.value = @"John User";
[[user updateAttributes:@[attribute]] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserUpdateAttributesResponse *> * _Nonnull task) {
    //success
    return nil;
}];
```

I would also like to state that the AWS API documentations for the iOS SDK are rather minimal, and I would recommend developers to go through the [SDK source code](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios) whenever in doubt.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer Arka! Really appreciated!